# Remover linha do rodapé

Tags: html, ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3

[image: rodapé]

Olá, alguém poderia me dar um help? não sei o que pode estar errado pois ja usei o no-lines antes em outro projeto e funcionou perfeitamente, mas aqui nao consigo remover essa linha por nada.
Pode ser algo bem simples mas ainda não achei a solução.

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="bg-style" no-padding>

<img src="assets/imgs/tela.png" height="150" width="490" style="display: 
 block;
 margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 150px">

<ion-footer no-lines class="footerlogo">
<ion-toolbar no-padding>
   <ion-item class="ionitem">
    <ion-title>

      <button ion-button secondary (click)="entrar(); alertaBasica()" 
    class="buttonlogo">ENTRAR</button>

    </ion-title>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>

  </ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```
page-logo {

background-color: #179c90 !important;


.footerlogo {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none  !important;
    outline-color: #179c90!important;

}

.buttonlogo {
    background-color: #179c90;

}

.ionitem{
    background: #179c90 !important;

}   

.bg-style {

    background: #179c90;
}


.toolbar-title{ text-align: left;
    padding-left: 36%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

}
```

Comment: Isso provavelmente é um background-image de alguma das diretivas!

Comment: Pode não ser esse o problema da linha, mas sugiro usar o `ion-footer` após o `ion-content`.

Comment: coloquei depois do ion-content. Usei  "<ion-footer no-lines class="footerlogo" no-border>"  , ainda tem a linha porém quase não é vista.  Um pouco melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Para remover essa linha basta adicionar `no-border` no `ion-footer`:

```
<ion-footer no-border class="footerlogo">
    <ion-toolbar no-padding>
        <ion-item class="ionitem">
            <ion-title>
                <button ion-button secondary (click)="entrar(); alertaBasica()" class="buttonlogo">ENTRAR</button>
            </ion-title>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Foi o que fiz, a linha continua porém quase não é vista. Obrigado por responder.

Comment: Entendi, é que você disse que colocou "no-lines", mas para não aparecer mesmo essa linha tem que ser "no-border".

Comment: Desculpe, vi agora só o no-border no final! hehehe